# Как защитится от повторной отправки формы через "Назад"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

У меня есть форма и контроллер, я не хочу что бы после заполнения формы пользователь мог нажать кнопку "Назад" в браузере и отправить идентичную форму опять. Я смотрел много ответов и попытался реализовать шаблон PRG, но он абсолютно ничем не помог, слышал что проблему можно как-то решить через AJAX, но я даже не знаю что это такое, ещё у меня есть баг, при удалении записи можно нажать "Назад" и 
"вернуть" её, хотя при обновлении страницы её уже нету, то-есть я хочу, что бы при переходе на некий адрес через "Назад" страничка всё-равно обновлялась. Мой код контроллера:

```
  @Controller
  public class libraryController {

@Autowired
private libraryService service;

@GetMapping("")
public String hello() {
    return "hello";
}

@GetMapping("/books")
public String getAll(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("books", service.findAll());

    return "books";
}

@PostMapping("/books")
public String add(@Valid @ModelAttribute("book") Book book, HttpServletResponse response,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value = "photo", required = false) MultipartFile photo, Model forExc, @RequestParam(value = "valute") String valute) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) return "addBook";
    if (!photo.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            validateImg(photo);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            result.reject("uk_UA", "Плохой тип изображения");
            return "addBook";
        }
    }
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("book", book);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("photo", photo);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("valute", valute);


    return "redirect:/valid";
}

@GetMapping("/valid")
public String validations(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Model model, @ModelAttribute("book") Book book, @ModelAttribute("valute") String valute, @ModelAttribute("photo") MultipartFile photo) {
     if (RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request)!=null) {
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         builder.append(service.download(photo));
         Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("SOMETHING HAS BROKEN IN LOGGING FILE");
         System.out.println("INSIDE ADD METHOD ");
         book.setFileId(builder.toString());
         service.add(book);

         HttpServletResponse httpres = (HttpServletResponse) response;
         httpres.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
         httpres.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
         httpres.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
         return "redirect:/books";
     }
     return "redirect:/index.jsp";

}


@GetMapping(value = "/books", params = "new")
public String addBook(Model model){
 model.addAttribute("book",new Book());
 return "addBook";
}


    public void validateImg(MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
    if (!file.getContentType().equals("image/jpeg")){
        throw new IOException("Only JPG images are accepted !");
    }
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String delete(@RequestParam("id") int id){
    service.delete(id);
    return "redirect:/books";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/desc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getFullDesc(@RequestParam("for") int id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("book",service.getById(id));
     return "fulldescription";

}
}
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь, спасибо.

Comment: Код контроллера тут не нужен. Все происходит на клиенте, т.е. в браузере. Вам нужно организовать правильную работу кода JS в Вашем приложении. А для этого, как минимум, придется всё-таки выяснить, что же такое AJAX.

Comment: Ок, а для того что бы решить вторую проблему ( заставить страничку обновляться, даже когда на неё переходят через "Назад"), тоже нужно рыть в сторону JS?

Comment: Тут могут быть варианты, но для начала, да, смотреть в сторону JS.

Comment: Возможно, примите меня за сумасшедшего, но я решил проблему путём создания < input > с типом hidden, в котором генерируется уникальный, рандомный "ключ", который после передается контроллеру и тот, если ключа нету в списке таких же ключей, либо добавляет в БД книгу, либо отменяет запрос создания книги, скорее всего сделать можно лучше, но как по мне лучше, чем каждый раз бегать в БД.